# How to add controls on form depending on country that is chosen in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, devexpress

I have a tab control which contains the country list in comboedit. I want to display Address format & the controls dyanamically as per order specifed as per company choosen from comboedit. We will make different formats for each country in first
group, whereas all countries in the second group will share a common format. We
will keep Australia, USA and UK in the first group. You can see the address
format at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195167.aspx.

The addresses for companies in first group should show the
relevant fields in the order specified in database, as soon as user chooses country.

Any suggestion?

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of ContentControl, ContentTemplateSelector and DataTemplateSelector.

```
    public class AddressTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        string addressStr = item as string;
        if (addressStr == "Australia")
            return (DataTemplate)Application.Current.FindResource("AutstraliaAddressResource");

        return (DataTemplate)Application.Current.FindResource("DefaultAddressResource");
    }
}
```

Define resources in App.xaml

Checkout below links for more information
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348820.aspx